# Facebook comments box not appearing in Wordpress posts

Tags: facebook, wordpress, plugins, comments

Here is my problem. On my Wordpress blog I'm using Facebook plugin (the one provided by Facebook). So far it was doing great job for me. Untill today. Today I saw, that the comments box remains empty, even though the website is already loaded. That occures ONLY, when I'm logged on my Facebook account. When someone else is logged in, comment box works fine. What could be the reason of that weird situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it's related to this issue https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/383938611736678?browse=external_tasks_search_results_5269147c9fefb2567094629

Seems to be a problem with the Facebook comments plugin itself.

Comment: No problem, I also have issues with it. Hope they will fix it soon :)